# Can a JAR built in Java 11 run in Java 17? (From older SDK to never SDK)

Tags: java, jar, java-11, java-17

I have an application and I built a JAR file using Java 11. However, it is required to upgrade to Java 17 in near future. What I want to clarify is that still a JAR built in Java 11 runs in Java 17 environment. I tried it and it worked fine without any issue? I just wanna ask from the community whether is there any possibility to face different issues during this process? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can newer versions of java run on older versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65850230/can-newer-versions-of-java-run-on-older-versions)

Comment: Generally yes.  However, there are things that you can do in Java 11 that may stop working in Java 17.  For example dependencies on JDK internals, stuff involving `SecurityManager`, `Applet` etcetera,

Comment: @JackLam - That question is actually about the reverse scenario.  (Though it is not clear from its title.)